# How to create a wireless hotspot from 3G connection in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

If I wanted to, how would I create an app like [MyWi](http://intelliborn.com/mywi.html), i.e. a wifi tethering app? What are the steps to achieve this functionality? What frameworks/libraries would I need to use?

The goal is not to try to get this app into the app store, but to have it for personal use, and provide it to others.

EDIT: 
Nick pointed out the [HandyLight app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlarDCHCyXA), an app that provided tethering capability disguised as a flashlight. So, it is possible to provide tethering functionality via a third-party app on a non-jailbroken phone. So how is this done?

I have sort of hit a dead end on my research for this :(

Comment: A good question but you could add some more of your own research on this topic. As for running MyWi on your non-jailbroken iPhone. It depends on why MyWi is not in AppStore. If it's merely because of usage of private APIs - then you could; it it's because it uses functions not available on non-jailbroken iPhone - than you couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a developer account (or know someone who does), you can build your own copy of iProxy, an open-source proxy app that handles this. You'll never find it in the App Store, but the source is available on github: https://github.com/tcurdt/iProxy

No jailbreak required, and it works well. Note that I wouldn't recommend using it too often, however, as carriers like to sell their own golden-egg tethering plans, and may ping you for the data usage.

Comment: I've used this before.  It does work but it's a pain to set up.  Something to consider is that on AT&T at least, if you enable tethering for just a day you'll be charged only the pro-rated rate for the tethering data plan for that day.  So if you only use it sometimes (like at an airport) it makes more sense just to use carrier tethering.

Comment: Use this version instead: https://github.com/atomicbird/iProxy/ . It's a fork of iProxy that actually builds in Xcode 4. Totally works!

Answer (score 0):

If you release it to the AppStore, Apple will not allow it. That's why there aren't any out there. There was a flashlight app which had the hidden wifi hotspot in it until someone posted a review comment of "WIFI TETHERING!!11!!!!!". Then Apple pulled it.

The iPhone has built in WiFi tethering - they call it "Personal Hotspot", but unless you have an unlocked phone direct from Apple (ie you paid in full with no contract), then you will have to pay your network provider more money to be able to turn it on.

Comment: Hey Nick. Thanks for you answer!
I'm more interested in _how_ one would go about writing an app to do this.

Comment: btw, thanks for providing the HandyLight example. That shows that tethering can be done by third-party apps on non-jailbroken phones.