# Is it possible to programmatically enable hotspot mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, wifi

I want to develop an application that programmatically creates a Personal Hotspot with a predefined name on an iPhone.

Is it possible?

Comment: There is no way to control network settings.
You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110276/how-to-create-a-wireless-hotspot-from-3g-connection-in-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a HotSpot in code talking via an API or via a [Configuration Profile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Have you looked at [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/Introduction/Introduction.html) which does a great job of easing connecting devices transparently via Bluetooth or WiFi? Don't let the "Game" name fool you - it's a great and easy to use library.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to put the time and work in to build it, sure.

However, you can *only* do it for jailbroken phones, and you would need to interface the private API:s. If you still want to do it, a starting point could be to go through the private API:s documented here: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers